How to access query in an NextApiRequest
I am trying to access the the query in my http request with the following url http://localhost:3000/api/hello?type=customer does anyone know how to retrive the value of type?
export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET']);
    return res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
}

const cusID = "**************";
const pmID = "******************";
console.log(req.query) // undefined
const type = req.query.type;


try {
    if (type === 'paymentMethod') {
        const paymentMethod = await stripe.customers.retrievePaymentMethod(cusID, pmID);
        console.log(paymentMethod);
        return res.status(200).json(paymentMethod);
    } else if (type === 'customer') {
        const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(cusID);
        console.log('Customer:', customer);
        return res.status(200).json(customer);
    } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "No valid query parameter provided" });
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
}

}

Problem :

I am trying to access the the query in my http request with the following url

Possible Cause :

Improper way of accessing query

Possible Solution :
Use nextUrl to access query (type) :
const type = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('type')


Please Read :

URL Query Parameters : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#url-query-parameters
nextUrl : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-request#nexturl


If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)

